# How to make facebook like button counter count only likes?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I could not find a solved post with similar problem and I could really use some help.

Basically I have implemented facebook likes button with a counter (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button).

However the counter takes the number of comments into consideration when displaying like count:
for example, the counter shows 100 likes on url. However facebook graph api shows that said url's `like_count` is actually 60 and its `comment_count` is 40.

What I need is for a like button counter to display on the amount of likes, not comments or shares.

Is that possible without making my own custom facebook like button?